# DSharpPlus Change Discord Embed Color

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

I want to do a Button that changes the Color of an Embed, in the Message, that the button belongs to.

```
var message = e.interaction.message;

await message.ModifyAsync(/*Change Color of Embed*/);
```

The problem is that I have no Idea of how to change the Color...

The nearest solution I've found was to create an new Embed, with that Color, and change the existend Embed with the new one, but then I've got another Problem:
If I try make an new Embed, I need a way to get the specific Title and Description of the Embed, but I also didn't find a way to get this...

```
var oldEmbedMessage = message.Embeds;

var newEmbedMessage = new DiscordEmbedBuilder() 
{
    Title = oldEmbedMessage./*Get Title*/;
    Description = oldEmbedMessage./*Get Description*/;
    Color = DiscordColor.Yellow
}
```

Comment: I got it!
You need to get the old Embed, and create a new embed with all the Components, and just change the Color like this:
var embed = (DiscordEmbed)message.Embeds[0];
var newEmbed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder()
{
    Title = embed.Title,
    Description = embed.Description,
    Color = DiscordColor.Yellow
};